# Google Chrome set default for tel links

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing my first Chrome extension and I need to add a functionality to handle phone links. Searching the documentation and web has left me with no straight answer.

In the latest build when you click on a "tel:" link then it opens a prompt titled "Make a call from". What I need is to set a default so that it no longer brings this prompt up and just sends the number to my chosen application.

Can I hardcode the default application (somehow with protocol handlers?) or is it possible to add a checkbox so that it remembers the chosen application as default?

I tried the registry method of adding *"ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox"* but that did not work.